# Control fan speed with PCA9685 and a PIC

Tags: pic, pwm, servo, motordriver, dc

I would like to control the speed of various motors using a PIC and PCA9685.

This following code allow me to start the rotation, but it does not reduce the speed

```
void pca9685_Set_rate(int address, int rate)
{
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(address);
    i2c_write(MODE1);
    i2c_write(Sleep);
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(address);
    i2c_write(PreScale);
    i2c_write(rate);
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(address);
    i2c_write(MODE1);
    i2c_write(PCA9685AI);  // Set MODE1 back to INT_CLK, AutoIncrement, Normal
    i2c_stop();

    __delay_us(500);       // Required for PCA oscillator startup
}

void pca9685_Set_speed(int address, int line, int speed)
{
    unsigned int on_count  = 0;
    unsigned int off_count = speed;

    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(address);
    i2c_write((line*4) + 6);
    i2c_write(on_count);        // Writing 8 LSB bits of ON count
    i2c_write(on_count >> 8);   // Writing 4 MSB bits of ON count
    i2c_write(off_count);       // Writing 8 LSB bits of OFF count
    i2c_write(off_count >> 8);  // Writing 4 MSB bits of ON count
    i2c_stop();
}
```

in the main():

```
enter code here
pca9685_Set_rate(0x80, 0x03); // 1600
ledn = 1;

pca9685_Set_speed(0x80, ledn, 4095);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);

pca9685_Set_speed(0x80, ledn, 3500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);

pca9685_Set_speed(0x80, ledn, 3000);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);

pca9685_Set_speed(0x80, ledn, 2500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);
DelayMs(500);

pca9685_Set_speed(0x80, ledn, 2000);
```

I am using a single MOSFET on PCA9685 out to convert the level to 12 V.

Could be this the problem?  Must I use a TB6612 or a DRV8833?

Comment: Have you put an oscilloscope on pin 7 to see if the pulse train looks correct?  Did you really intend to write to LED1, and not LED0 (pin 6)?  I suppose if it is turning on at all, then the connections are OK.

Comment: If I connect a led with a 470ohm in series on the pca9685 out led1, I see a different values of light and I can measure dc voltage from 4.24, 3.6 ... 0.5 but the motor connected after the mosfet work only when the voltage is 4.24.

Comment: But this is supposed to be a PWM, right?  It's not a DAC.  It should be a fixed voltage with a varying duty cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by adding a 2.2 kΩ resistor and a [TIP120](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip120.pdf) (power transistor) on any output, so for each 12 V DC fan.

The code is OK.

Comment: What kind of circuit? A [collector follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter)? With a base resistor?